# How can I determine when the most recent Google Glass update occurred on my GoogleGlass device?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

**How can I get the last update date for Google Glasses**? Now it's 19.1, and I really need to know when it was updated to the current version programatically.

Thank you!

Comment: I think its not possible.Glass will not provide such kind of information.

Comment: Unless you're talking about how to find this date via code, this question is off-topic for [so].

Comment: I want to find the date in any manner possible(even via code). Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Why do you need to know that date or even hour? I can't think of an use case for that information...

Answer (score 2):

The developer release notes for each version are at https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes. Updates roll out within a week or so of this date.

Comment: Indeed, I saw the roll out dates, but in my case I need to know the exact day when my Glass updated (even hour).

Answer (score 0):

While you can get the Build version and other information with code (see Android.os.Build [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)), the date that the current Build was loaded (updated) is not currently available.

You could consider having your application store the version that it was in place when initially installed, and do some sort of check when the version changes ....